# How to Require list of images inside react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Guys I'm trying to make a require some images and putting every image in backgroundImage in css
Code:

```js
BackgroundsItems.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div  key={index} className="item-outer" id="item-outer" style={{
                                background: `url(${require(`${item.Img}`)})`,
                                backgroundPosition: 'center',
                                backgroundSize: 'cover',
                                backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'
                            }}> 
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
```

and this is the BackgroundsItems code:

```js
const BackgroundsItems = []
for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    let Format = "00";
    let fileEx = "jpg"
    if (i >= 9) Format = "0";
    if (i == 0) fileEx = "png"
    BackgroundsItems.push({
        price: 5000,
        Img: `./imgs/${Format + (i + 1)}.${fileEx}`,
        id: Format + (i + 1)
    })
}

export { BackgroundsItems };
```

everything working well but the image does not shown  , i hope if someone understand me

Update: Solved By adding default after requre the image

```js
BackgroundsItems.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div  key={index} className="item-outer" id="item-outer" style={{
                                background: `url(${require(`${item.Img}`).default})`,
                                backgroundPosition: 'center',
                                backgroundSize: 'cover',
                                backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'
                            }}> 
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
```

Comment: Instead of editing your question, answer your question in the proper section.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already found the answer :) You can also simply remove require.